# How to merge folders in every subdirectory using python code?

Tags: python, merge, directory, directory-structure

my directory now.[1]
I want to combine every Sub in every Folder so it should look something like this [2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz7FJ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scK48.png

Comment: Are there nested dirs under sub1 as well?

Comment: no @Jay sub1 has all the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all the files/dirs in a directory using [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

We are just iterating over all files in a dir and then moving them to a destination directory using [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename)

```
import os
directory = '/tmp/dataset'

def move_all_files_to_destination_dir(original_dir, destination_dir):
    # moves all NESTED files in original_dir to destination_dir
    files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(original_dir):
        for name in files:
            os.rename(root + os.sep + name, destination_dir + os.sep + name)
    
subdirs = [f.path for f in os.scandir(directory) if f.is_dir()]   # [Folder1, Folder2]
for d in subdirs:
    move_all_files_to_destination_dir(d, d)
    # remove the subdirectories of d after we have moved all files under it
    for sub in os.scandir(d):
        if sub.is_dir():
            shutil.rmtree(sub)
```

Comment: Thanks!!... this works perfectlty while merging subfolders.. but it does not delete the sub folders.. giving error as follows (usiing this code on google colab) :                                                                                               OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/content/Indic-Leaf-Dataset/indic_leaf_dataset/50_caladium_bicolor'

Comment: thank you for update... this also worked until merging part.. when deleting the Sub in Folder1, it deletes the entire Folder1

Comment: Got it, updated the answer to delete the subdirs of d instead of directory itself to which we have moved the new files